# Cannot authorize Google Data Transfer API in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I have an Appscript app that uses [Google's OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs) to perform a variety of functions on a G suite domain.  I wanted to add the ability to transfer user data using the [Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer) but I'm having trouble authorizing the service. I have no issues authorizing the gmail, drive, and directory APIs and I made sure the service is on in the GCP project. However, I can't get my OAuth2 service to authorize, I get the logged message that my service account isn't authorized each time. What's missing here?

Here's my code:

```
const migrationScope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.datatransfer'];

function migrateUser(sourceUser, targetUser, type) {
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/datatransfer/v1/transfers';
  var service = getService_('superadmin_account@company.com', 'admin', migrationScope);
  var transferObject = {
    oldOwnerUSerId: getUserId(sourceUser), // this takes an email and returns the user ID which is required by the API
    newOwnerUserId: getUserId(targetUser),
    applicationDataTransfers: [
      {
        applicationTransferParams: [
          {
            value: type,
          }
        ],
        applicationId: 5********6 // Our App ID for Drive
      }
    ]
  }
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBuilder(service, transferObject, 'POST'));
    try {
      var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
      return (result);
    }
    catch (e) {
      return (undefined);
    }
  } else { Logger.log("Service does not have access to migrate content."); }
}

function getService_(email, service, scopes) {
  return OAuth2.createService(service + ':' + email)
    .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token').
    .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)
    .setSubject(email)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
    .setScope(scopes);
}
function requestBuilder(service, payload, method) {
  return {
    method: method,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code itself seems to be all right, assuming that `requestBuilder` returns the correctly formatted advanced parameters for the [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) call.

Considering the kind of error you're getting, I think you didn't add the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.datatransfer` on the **Domain wide delegation** pane on the Admin console.

When using the service account to impersonate other users, you need to add to this pane any scope which the service account should be able to access. It's not enough that the API is enabled on the GCP project or that the scope is added to the consent screen. You need to add them there too.

To do that, follow these steps, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority):

> Then, a super administrator of the G Suite domain must complete the following steps:
> 1. From your G Suite domain’s [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/), go to **Main menu > Security > API Controls**.
> 2. In the **Domain wide delegation** pane, select **Manage Domain Wide Delegation**.
> 3. Click **Add new**.
> 4. In the **Client ID** field, enter the service account's **Client ID**. You can find your service account's client ID in the [Service accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).
> 5. In the **OAuth scopes (comma-delimited)** field, enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to. For example, if your application needs domain-wide full access to the Google Drive API and the Google Calendar API, enter:
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`.
> 6. Click **Authorize**.

#### Important note:

- Make sure the service account is impersonating a user (`.setSubject(email)`) who has the appropriate admin privileges to actually transfer data.

#### Reference:

- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot to update that page, so I added the scope and waited a bit, but it seems I'm still getting the error. I've tried setting the `setSubject` user to both a superadmin account and one with the Drive settings and Data transfer admin role but I get the same error. I also added my request builder function to the question.

Comment: Nevermind, got it! There was issues elsewhere that I made while trying to debug. Thank you!